# The XML parser detected error code 302

Tags: rpgle, rpg

I am using the XML-INTO op-code to parse a web service request.  Every now and then I get errors in the logs

```
(RNX0351 - "The XML parser detected error code 302").
```

The help for a 302 is

```
302 The parser does not support the requested CCSID value or 
the first character of the XML document was not '<'
```

To the best of my knowledge, the first character is "<" and the request is generated from a previous web service call so I would be very suprised if the CCSID has changed.

The error is repeatable, for the specific query so it is almost certainly data related, I am just unsure how I would go about identifying the offending item.

Any thoughts on how to determine the issue, or better yet, how to overcome it?

cheers

Comment: I suggest dumping the XML string you're processing - that way you can confirm the first character is a `<` and not a NULL, BOM or something else.

Comment: The request is written to IFS at the start of processing, and is the "<" from the start of the soap envelope, no blanks, nulls or binaries, so far as I can tell.  The request is an update and the source is a "get" that occurred immediately prior from same server, , perform a similar update on a different record and it works happily, hence my belief it is data related.

Comment: What is the CCSID of the file in the IFS?

Comment: CCSID is 1252  Same as all the rest from our server.  thats the bit that makes no sense, it is the same application calling these services.  All internal, all consistent - I thought!

Comment: If it makes any difference to anyone, the CCSID is 1252, the first character is "<", hex value 3C.  I cannot see any evidence of BOM's but I can reproduce the issue at will.
The flow of operations is our java front end gets data from the iSeries, then sends an update request.  It is the same application at all times, not some random guest consumer.

Comment: In the last project I worked on that parsed a SOAP response there was a BOM between the `<s:Envelope><s:Body><ThirdPartyXMLTag>` and the beginning of the XML payload. So after I used XML-SAX to peel off the outer XML elements mentioned I had to skip the first 3 bytes of the payload to get past the BOM.

Comment: Sorry for late reply - thanks guys, I will have a closer look at these areas.  The server, I have just discovered is running under CCSID of 37, the 1252 is just the CCSID of the file that is written to IFS.

Answer (score 2):

CCSID is an AS400/iSeries/Power System attribute, and it applies to the whole IFS.
It's like a declaration of what inside the file is, or in other words what its internal encoding "should be".
It's supposed that data content encoding in the file and the file one (the envelope) match, and the box uses this attribute to show and handle corresponding characters.
It sounds like you receive data under one encoding, but CCSID file doesn't match.
Try changing CCSID on your file (only the envelope). E.G.: 37 (american), 500 (latin-1), 819 (utf-8), 850 (dos), 1252 (win) and display file after.
You can check first using ls -Sla yourfile in QSH or QP2TERM, or EDTF as well. CHGATTR allows you to change CCSID, as well as setccsid in QSH (again).
This way helped me to find related issues. Remember that although data may be visible in the four hundred, they may not be visible through a share folder in Win. It means that CCSID file, an content encoding don't match.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I've seen this error with XML data uploaded to AS400/iSeries/IBM i with FTP and the CCSID 819 (ISO 8859-1 ASCII) and it has some binary garbage in first few positions of file. Changed encoding to CCSID 1208 (UTF-8 with IBM PUA) using FTP "quote type c 1208" and the problem cleared and XML-INTO was successful.

So, suggestion about XML parser error 302 received when using XML-INTO is to look at the file (wrklnk ...) and if first character is not "<" but instead some binary garbage then try CCSID 1208 for utf-8.

Statements in this answer about what 819 is and what ccsid represents utf-8 do not agree with previous answer but are correct, according to IBM documentation:
https://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/ccsid/ccsid819.html
https://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/ccsid/ccsid1208.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this problem a couple hours,

for me the solution was use option ccsid=UCS2 when you use data structure or variable to store xml.

something like that :

XML-INTO customer %XML( xmlSource : 'ccsid=UCS2');

I have the program running on ccsid = 870, every conversion to ccsid on the xmlSource field don't work, 
The strange thing that when I use the file with ccsid = 850, every thing work fine

I mention that becouse this is the first page when you looking about this problem.
Maybe this help someone.